# Problema con función ".map" al mostrar datos en Gráfico Chart.js trayendo desde RDS

Tags: mysql, express, chart.js, lambda, amazon-rds

Tengo un problema, y es que estoy mostrando datos dinámicos de un gráfico con Chart.js, los datos vienen de la base de datos, y con esos datos se va armando el gráfico, el problema es que me está arrojando un error la función "map", a nivel de "localhost" funciona y trae los datos de la base de datos de AWS RDS y los muestra sin problemas pero al subirlo a AWS, me arroja ese error.

Pensé que era por la IP, que no tenía habilitado para realizar consultas a la base con cualquier IP pero lo modifiqué y sigue el mismo error.

Estoy usando Lambda con Express como servidor "serverless", API GATEWAY y AWS RDS.

Este es mi código:

**grafico.js**

```
let url = new URL(document.location.href);
let urln = document.location.pathname;
let regTransform = urln.replace(/\/dev\/grafico\//, '');
const nombreIndice = regTransform;
        const ctx = document.querySelector('#chart').getContext('2d');
        const image = new Image();
        image.src = '/img/logo-invrtir-charts.svg';
        const plugin = {
            id: 'custom_canvas_background_image',
            beforeDraw: (chart) => {
                if (image.complete) {
                const ctx = chart.ctx;
                const {top, left, width, height} = chart.chartArea;
                const x = left + width / 2 - image.width / 2;
                const y = top + height / 2 - image.height / 2;
                ctx.drawImage(image, x, y);
                } else {
                image.onload = () => chart.draw();
                }
            }
        };

        function totalChart(ctx, extraerdatos){
            const chart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels: extraerdatos.map(item => new Intl.DateTimeFormat('ex-EC', {
                        month: 'short',
                        day: 'numeric'
                    }).format(new Date(item.fecha))),
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'Precio Real',
                        data: extraerdatos.map((item) => {
                            if(item.preop > 0){
                                return item.preop;
                            }
                        }),
                        borderColor: '#ff944c',
                        backgroundColor: '#ff944c',
                        radius: 0
                        //Agregar Puntos
                    }, {
                        label: 'Precio Actual', 
                        data: extraerdatos.map((item) => {
                            if(item.propost > 0){
                                return item.propost;
                            }
                        }),
                        borderColor: '#ff944c',
                        backgroundColor: '#ff944c',
                        borderDash: [2],
                        radius: 0
                        //Editar Line Style - Agregar Puntos
                    }, {
                        label: 'P1',
                        data: extraerdatos.map((item) => {
                            if(item.p1 > 0){
                                return item.p1;
                            }
                        }),
                        borderColor: '#70a5f5',
                        backgroundColor: '#70a5f5',
                        radius: 0
                    }, {
                        label: 'P2',
                        data: extraerdatos.map((item) => {
                            if(item.p2 > 0){
                                return item.p2;
                            }
                        }),
                        borderColor: 'violet',
                        backgroundColor: 'violet',
                        radius: 0
                    }, {
                        label: 'P3',
                        data: extraerdatos.map((item) => {
                            if(item.p3 > 0){
                                return item.p3;
                            }
                        }),
                        borderColor: 'violet',
                        backgroundColor: 'violet',
                        radius: 0
                    },{
                        label: 'P4',
                        data: extraerdatos.map((item) => {
                            if(item.p4 > 0){
                                return item.p4;
                            }
                        }),
                        borderColor: 'violet',
                        backgroundColor: 'violet',
                        radius: 0
                    },{
                        label: 'PM',
                        data: extraerdatos.map((item) => {
                            if(item.pm > 0){
                                return item.pm;
                            }
                        }),
                        borderColor: '#00aa00',
                        backgroundColor: '#00aa00',
                        radius: 0
                    }, {
                        label: 'PM2',
                        data: extraerdatos.map((item) => {
                            if(item.pm2 > 0){
                                return item.pm2;
                            }
                        }),
                        borderColor: '#00aa00',
                        backgroundColor: '#00aa00',
                        radius: 0
                    },{
                        label: 'SL',
                        data: extraerdatos.map((item) => {
                            if(item.sl > 0){
                                return item.sl;
                            }
                        }),
                        borderColor: '#ff4c4d',
                        backgroundColor: '#ff4c4d',
                        radius: 0
                    }]
                },
                plugins: [plugin],
                options: {
                    layout: {
                        padding: {
                            left: 0,
                            right: 0
                        },
                    },
                    interaction: {
                        mode: 'index',
                        intersect: false,
                    },
                    responsive: true,
                    maintainAspectRatio: false,
                    scales: {
                        x: {
                            grid: {
                                display: false
                            },
                            ticks: {
                                callback: function(val, index) {
                                    return index % 15 === 0 ? this.getLabelForValue(val) : '';
                                },
                                maxRotation: 0,

                            },
                        },
                        y: {
                            grid: {
                                display: false
                            },
                        },
                    },
                    elements: {
                        line: {
                            borderWidth: 3,
                            fill: false,
                        },
                        point: {
                            pointStyles: 'line'
                        }
                    },
                    plugins: {
                        title: {
                            display: false,
                            text: nombreIndice,
                            font: {
                                size: 15,
                            },
                            color: '#FFF',
                            padding: 30
                        },
                        legend: {
                            position: 'bottom',
                            labels: {
                                padding: 20,
                                boxWidth: 2,
                                boxHeight: 2,
                                color: '#797b86',
                                font: {
                                    family: 'system-ui',
                                    size: 7
                                },
                            }
                        },
                        tooltip: {
                            backgroundColor: '#0584f6',
                            titleFontSize: 20,
                            xPadding: 20,
                            yPadding: 20,
                            bodyFontSize: 15,
                            bodySpacing: 10,
                            mode: 'x'
                        },
                    }
                },
                
            });
            for (let i = 0; i < extraerdatos.length; i++) {
                var p3Var = extraerdatos[i].p3++;
            }
            for (let i = 0; i < extraerdatos.length; i++) {
                var p4Var = extraerdatos[i].p4++;
            }
            for (let i = 0; i < extraerdatos.length; i++) {
                var pm2Var = extraerdatos[i].pm2++;
            }
            if (p3Var===0 && p4Var===0 && pm2Var===0) {
                chart.data.datasets.splice(4, 2);
                chart.data.datasets.splice(5, 1);
            }else if (p3Var===0 && p4Var===0 && pm2Var!=0){
                chart.data.datasets.splice(4, 2);
            }else if (p3Var===0 && p4Var!=0 && pm2Var===0) {
                chart.data.datasets.splice(4, 1);
                chart.data.datasets.splice(6, 1);
            }else if (p3Var===0 && p4Var!=0 && pm2Var!=0) {
                chart.data.datasets.splice(4, 1);
            }else if (p3Var!=0 && p4Var===0 && pm2Var===0) {
                chart.data.datasets.splice(5, 1);
                chart.data.datasets.splice(6, 1);
            }else if (p3Var!=0 && p4Var===0 && pm2Var!=0) {
                chart.data.datasets.splice(5, 1);
            }else if (p3Var!=0 && p4Var!=0 && pm2Var===0) {
                chart.data.datasets.splice(7, 1);
            }
            chart.update();
            if (chart.legend.legendItems.length >= 0) {
                chart.legend.legendItems.splice(1, 1);
            }
        }
        async function renderizarCharts() {
            const respuesta = await fetch('/graficos/grafico/' + nombreIndice).then((res) => {
                return res.json();
            }).then((json) => {
                var extraerDatos = json;
                totalChart(ctx, extraerDatos);
            });
        }
        renderizarCharts();
```

**graficos.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const pool = require('../database');

router.get('/grafico/:indice', async (req, res) => {
    const time = new Date();
    const day = time.getDate();
    time.setDate(day+15);
    const month = time.getMonth() + 1;
    const timeQuery = time.getFullYear() + '-' + month + '-' + time.getDate();
    const { indice } = req.params;
    const datos = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM datos WHERE indice = ? AND fecha <= ?', [indice, timeQuery]);
    const datosExtraidos = JSON.stringify(datos);
    res.send(datosExtraidos);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Y este es el error:

```
main.js?attr=6Bjd7U1eVWxRrCApX5Hu3iTa8nCD9p_YHwolliF3SB1Y6Q_XOSzZ_LjCvtFHdx1ZHT41qB5HIAD8rVEeux4VdtHQiwf-WRRkyLJ57KhMIYqYx2Kua64CEjO7U9zvIFqN:2671 GET https://oabb7m937k.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/grafico/UNH.44361 403
fetchCallImpl @ main.js?attr=6Bjd7U1eVWxRrCApX5Hu3iTa8nCD9p_YHwolliF3SB1Y6Q_XOSzZ_LjCvtFHdx1ZHT41qB5HIAD8rVEeux4VdtHQiwf-WRRkyLJ57KhMIYqYx2Kua64CEjO7U9zvIFqN:2671
window.fetch @ main.js?attr=6Bjd7U1eVWxRrCApX5Hu3iTa8nCD9p_YHwolliF3SB1Y6Q_XOSzZ_LjCvtFHdx1ZHT41qB5HIAD8rVEeux4VdtHQiwf-WRRkyLJ57KhMIYqYx2Kua64CEjO7U9zvIFqN:2673
renderizarCharts @ grafico.js:237
(anonymous) @ grafico.js:244
grafico.js:27 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: extraerdatos.map is not a function
    at totalChart (grafico.js:27)
    at grafico.js:241
    at async renderizarCharts (grafico.js:237)
totalChart @ grafico.js:27
(anonymous) @ grafico.js:241
async function (async)
renderizarCharts @ grafico.js:239
(anonymous) @ grafico.js:244
favicon.ico:1 GET https://oabb7m937k.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/favicon.ico 403
```

[image: Error función .map]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya conseguí la solución, era un problema con el endpoint.

Tenía que agregar "/dev/" al principio de las URL del código.